# Is there a way I can add a class to a row in an ng-repeat when a cell is hovered over?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

If I have HTML like this:

```
<div style="display: table">
   <div style="display: table-row; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2px;"
        ng-class="{clicked: row.current == true}"
        ng-click="home.rowClicked($index)"
        ng-dblclick="ctrl.rowDoubleClicked(row)"
       ng-repeat="row in home.grid.data">
      <div style="display: table-cell">{{ row.abc }}</div>
      <div style="display: table-cell">{{ row.def }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can change the class of the row when a user hovers over either of the two divs? Note that I just added the inline CSS so people could see that I was using display: table-row.

The reason I would like to do this is because I want to change the background color of all the cells in a row as the user hovers over just one cell in that row. If there is another way to do this then I would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add class for example via jQuery. But in your case just add your table row any class eg. `row` and add this line in your .css file:

```
.row:hover {backgroud-color: yellow;}
```